# How does method chaining work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How does method chaining work in ruby? As a C# developer, when I see `1.hour.from_now.localtime`, I'm not sure what's going on. How does this code work?

```
<%= 1.hour.from_now.localtime %>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`1` is an object that responds to hour

```
pry(main)> 1.class
=> Fixnum
```

`.hour` is a method on Fixnum that signifies it as an hour (by changing it to 3600)

```
pry(main)> 1.hour.class
=> Fixnum
pry(main)> 1.hour.to_i
=> 3600
```

`.from_now` changes the type of `3600` to a DateTime, 3600 seconds in to the future.

```
pry(main)> 1.hour.from_now
=> Mon, 22 Sep 2014 19:57:05 UTC +00:00
pry(main)> 1.hour.from_now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

`.localtime` changes the TimeZone to the system local time:

```
pry(main)> 1.hour.from_now.localtime
=> 2014-09-22 12:57:41 -0700
```

Comment: Also methods always returns something, and the chained methods applies to this response.
1 returns 1 .hour returns "3600 seconds" .from_now returns a datetime .localtime applies timezone.

Answer (score 5):

Everything in Ruby is an object, so in this case:

- The Fixnum `1` object receives the message `hour`

  - Which returns a Fixnum of seconds
- `3600 seconds` receives the message `from_now`

  - Which returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object
  - Essentially it offsets the current time (the `from_now`) by an offset (our initial Fixnum of seconds)
- This Time object then receives the message `localtime`

  - This converts the TimeWithZone object from UTC to your local timezone

    - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-localtime

If you want to explore each step, you can use the rails console and evaluate each step to see the return value (and call `class` on each step to see how it changes the type)